# CppCheck does not detect memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, cppcheck

Have following code, but CppCheck(1.68) detects only "style" error.

```
AbstractTelegram *TelegramFactory::CreateGetWigWagParameterTelegram(BYTE     Address_i, BYTE SubAddress_i, BYTE Tag_i)
{
   SignDataWigWag *pWigWag = new SignDataWigWag();

   return new SendTelegram(SubAddress_i, Tag_i, Telegram::GET_WIG_WAG,NULL,0);
}
```

Output:

```
Variable 'pWigWag' is assigned a value that is never used.
Variable 'pWigWag' is assigned a value that is never used.
```

Any options to tune?

Answer (score 3):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

Actually.. we can't see that there is definitely a memory leak in that code.

There are classes that has automatic memory management.

Imagine for example that the SignDataWigWag constructor has such code:

```
SignDataWigWag::SignDataWigWag() {
    instances.push_back(this);
}
```

then it can be deleted later by using for instance:

```
void deleteAllInstances() {
    while (!instances.empty()) {
        delete instances.back();
        instances.pop_back();
    }
}
```

This is not unusual. Some popular class libraries has lots of classes with some kind of memory management so manual delete is not needed..

Comment: there used to be an option to tune this. but as far as I know you can't tune this currently. maybe there will be an option to tune this better someday.

Answer (score 0):

cppcheck is essentially only a style-checker (and like other tools which incorporate the developer's notion of "good style", its usefulness depends on various factors).

There are suitable tools for detecting memory leaks (such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)); cppcheck is not one of those.  Of course, you will find differing opinions on which are the *best* tools, and even on what a tool is suitable for, e.g., a blog entry *[Valgrind is *NOT* a leak checker](http://maintainablecode.logdown.com/posts/245425-valgrind-is-not-a-leak-checker) *

Comment: What?
Do you understand the difference between static code analysis and run-time checks?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between constructive and constructive criticism?

Comment: I do, but, seems, you have problems reading the questions before replying.

Comment: I'm familiar with the tools available, and you have provided no evidence of that in any respect.

Comment: So, you still comparing valgrind and cppcheck, right?